# NetSuite Create Transfer Order from Sales Order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to write a script that will create a new transfer order from a sales order, copying all of the lines in the process. I have the script written, but I am getting an error that "define" is not defined. This script is modified from another script, so it is possible that I missed something. I am new to scripting, so I would appreciate any help and could do without criticism (even if my script is complete garbage).

```
/**
***************** ALEM ********************
* After Submit User Event script running on Sales Orders. Generates a TO.

*   Version    Date            Author           Remarks
*   1.0         9 Jan          madams          Initial Create
*/

/**
* @NApiVersion 2.0
* @NScriptType UserEventScript
* @NModuleScope Public
*
*/

define(['N/record',], function (record) {
  function afterSubmit(context) {
    if(context.type == 'delete'){
        log.debug('Exiting script', '...');
        return;
    }
    try{
    var so = record.load({
        type:'salesorder',
        id:context.newRecord.id
    });
    var so_items = so.getLineCount({sublistId:'item'});


    // Create new Transfer Order if Record is On Create.
     var to_record = record.create({
        type:'transferorder',
        isDynamic:true
    });

    to_record.setValue({fieldId:'customform', value:136});
    to_record.setValue({fieldId:'class', value:so.getValue('class')});
    to_record.setValue({fieldId:'transferlocation', 
value:so.getValue('location')});

    setLineItemsOnTO(so_items, to_record, so);

    to_record.setValue({fieldId:'custbody_related_record', 
value:context.newRecord.id});
    so.setValue({fieldId:'custbody_related_record', 
value:to_record.save()});
    so.setValue({fieldId:'orderstatus',value:'B'});
    so.save({ignoreMandatoryFields:true});
    } catch(e){
        log.debug('Error Loading Record' + context.newRecord.id, e);
        return;
    }

}
return {
    afterSubmit: afterSubmit
}

function setLineItemsOnTO(so_items, to_record, so){
     for(var i=0; i<so_items; i++){
        to_record.selectNewLine({sublistId:'item'});
        to_record.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId:'item',
            fieldId:'item',
            value:so.getSublistValue({
                sublistId:'item',
                fieldId:'item',
                line:i
            })
        });
        to_record.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId:'item',
            fieldId:'quantity',
            value:so.getSublistValue({
                sublistId:'item',
                fieldId:'quantity',
                line:i
            })
        });
        to_record.commitLine({sublistId:'item'});
    }
}

});
```

Comment: you need to import define or const define = require('< insert path to module > ')

Answer (score 1):

Did NetSuite import the script as SuiteScript 2.0? It probably imported the script as SS1.0.

The comment block containing @NApiVersion 2.0 needs to be the first comment block in the file. NetSuite looks for that block only at the top of the file to identify SS2.0 scripts.

Comment: Thank you, I moved the comment block to the top and it did upload as 2.0. That error went away, but now I am getting this error: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST","message":"Module does not exist: /SuiteScripts/user_so_create_to.js","stack":[]}

Comment: @M.Adams Did you check if the path in the error is the correct path to the js file.  Based on the error message, it is not finding the file.

Comment: Yes, I found another thread that solved the issue. I needed to add .js to the name of my script file.